# Is the gradient of a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^1$ the best $1$-dimensional approximated linear transformation at a point $v$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, jacobian, scalar-fields

I'm trying to get a better intuition regarding Jacobians. I think I have a decent understanding of gradients and what their directions mean, but I'm trying to connect all the dots for the generalisation of The Jacobian.

I understand that taking the Jacobian of a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^2$ would give us a 2 by 2 matrix that can be viewed as the best linear transformation at a certain point $v$, but what if the dimension of the function output is different from the input, as f.e with the gradient and scalar functions, would that give us the best approximated linear transformation in that other dimension?

What I'm asking is, if we view the gradient as a 1 by 2 matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}\partial f_x, \partial f_y \end{bmatrix}$ that we can use to transform other vectors, would that give us the best 1 dimensional approximated linear transformation at a certain point?

Comment: It would be valuable to precise what you mean by the *best $1$-dimensional approximated linear transformation*. At least, the gradient is the only one such that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\lvert f(a + h) - f(a) - \nabla f(a)\cdot h \rvert}{\lvert h \rVert} =0$.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been a bit unclear. If we view the gradient as a transformation $T(\textbf{x}) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the representation as a 2 by 1 matrix, when we plug in any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we are left with a 2 by 1 matrix that could be viewed as a linear transformation. Is this the best approximated linear transformation $L(\textbf{x}) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (from 2d to 1d) at that particular point of the original (non-linear?) transformation $T(\textbf{x}) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If you mean by *the best* the one that is locally the closest to the initial map, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Thanks a lot. I've only come across examples of $T(\textbf{x}) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^2$ and wanted to know if it generalised. Maybe I should use your wordings instead, "locally the closest linear transformation to the initial (non-linear?) transformation"

Comment: To talk about "the best", you should define what it means, for example with respect to some norm minimisation